# Unsure what PHP array is doing upon assigning

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have a DB snippit of code here...  I'll post the relevant lines without error checking to make it smaller...

```
if ($stmt->bind_result($row[0], $row[1]) === false) etc...
```

then below I have...

```
<pre><code>
    //fill the array up with an array of rows, then increment $ddp.
    //$data[$ddp] is the row,
    //$data[$dpp][0] is the rows first argument,
    //$data[$dpp][1] is the rows 2nd argument returned etc...

    $ddp = 0; // this increments up every fetch

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $data[$ddp][0] = $row[0];
        $data[$ddp][1] = $row[1];
        $ddp++;
    }
</code></pre>
```

The way I have it above WORKS....   but here is how I did it before and something weird was happening...

```
<pre><code>
    $ddp = 0; // this increments up every fetch

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $data[$ddp++] = $row;
        // I ECHOd out $row here... and it did fetch 2 different rows...
    }
</code></pre>
```

What happens is... when I did this...

```
$data[$ddp++] = $row;
```

`$data[0][0]` was the same as `$data[1][0]`.

Why then if `$row` had different values on the 2 fetches... how did `$data` end up with 2 arrays the same?

I even tried

```
$data[] = $row;
```

and the same results.  My fix was...

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $data[$ddp][0] = $row[0];
    $data[$ddp][1] = $row[1];
    $ddp++;
}
```

WHY?

Sorry if this isn't the right place to put this but I did find a solution ahead of time and to save time I posted the answer and my question together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your two assignments are doing two subtly different things.

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $data[$ddp][0] = $row[0];
    $data[$ddp][1] = $row[1];
    $ddp++;
}
```

This creates two entries in the array - the first will have the index `[0][0]`, and be assigned the value in `$row[0]`, and so on.

On the other hand, this:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $data[$ddp++] = $row;
    // I ECHOd out $row here... and it did fetch 2 different rows...
}
```

is adding a single row to the database, and adding the whole of `$row` to `$data[0]` on the first run through. So whatever is returned from the database is added as it is - if you're getting an array back from `fetch()`, then you're adding an array inside your array.

Comment: OH!!!   THANK YOU!!!   I didn't even notice that!   I'll accept your answer when the remaining time is up!  6 min left I believe!

Comment: In my mind... I was thinking... $row would be added to $data[$ddp++] like this..

$data[0] = array $row and automatically put in the $row[0] and the $row[1]!

Comment: Yes, $row is an array of 2 pieces of data.  When I did the improper way... both $data[0][0] and $data[1][0] held the SAME data (the LAST row to be retreived) which I found very weird...

Comment: I can't think of an easy way to do exactly that. Array manipulation can be frustrating, because both of these ways are valid (and you might choose one method over another at different times). To make things clearer, you might want to look at getting the data from the database as an Object, rather than array, so you have an array of objects instead - it's a little easier to keep track of.

Comment: Ah!  Good idea...  about the Object.  I'm new to OOP but I think I can work that in!  Much appreciated!!!

Comment: My server doesn't have `$stmt->get_result()->fetch_object()` or other variations on that.  Something about an myqlind or something file.  It's cool... I'm happy enough with [0][0] and [0][1].  Thx for the suggestion!  When they upgrade in the future I'll see about using that OOP Object approach!

Comment: Actually, in the future I'll be using PDO.  I only shied away from PDO because I read it didn't TRULY use Prepared Statements but emulated them.  BUT, afterwards I found out you can force it to use Prepared Statements with no fallback.  By then, I had my own MultiBind method.  I'll look into PDO in the future once my project is finished.